# Using an asp:Table for background in master page?

Tags: asp.net, css, master-pages, background-image

Here is my problem i want to use a table as a background image in my master page. But i couldn't find a way to display it as a background, what i need is the same effect as the microsoft Words wrap text behind text effect. While preserving relative positioning.

To sum up; i want to use an asp table sticky to bottom right corner of my webpage instead of body background image property.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Use a <div id="wrapper">, give it a position: relative;, use a <table>, give it position: absolute; and position it using offset properties bottom: 0; right: 0; Use z-index to "layer" the table.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot z-index is working like a charm, and layering was just the thing i wast trying to explain but now i have a problem with absolute positioning.
I can't align the table in the absolute bottom of the page its stuck in the middle and if you scroll down, it seems pretty absurd.

Also i'm pretty new in stackoverflow how do i vote your answer? =)

Comment: I made a comment instead of an answer so you can not vote comments up. Infact you can vote comments up, but it would not change or increase my points/reputation. And you can not mark the comment as "answered or accepted". See my below answer which you can both vote up and also mark as answered or accepted. (greedy me)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a div and place a table inside

```
<div id="wrapper">
<table>
</table>
</div>
```

Uss the following CSS

```
div#wrapper
{
position: relative;
}

div#wrapper>table
{
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
z-index: 999;
}
```

Regarding you comment, please note that the table will now to positioned "RELATIVE" to the div#wrapper. So with the above code, now the table will "sit" at the bottom right corner of the div#wrapper. If your table is "stuck" in the middle, than that is beacuse your div#wrapper may be in the middle. If you have some other element such as another div at the bottom of you page or a fotter div, you can use that instead of the div#wrapper. Or you could use the html/body elements, give either one of them a position of relative and than place the table in "RELATIVE" to the those elements.

Comment: You sir just made my day! Thank you! sadly i learned that i'm not able to vote your answer yet due to my rep =( but you have my endless gratitude! A Million Thanks!

Comment: @umutto: No worries mate. Happy it solved your problem. Good Luck.